# How to add dependency for new chrome for testing and its own driver, when chrome version is above 115?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, pom.xml, chrome-for-testing

How to add dependency for new chrome for testing and its own driver, when chrome version is above 115?
Cannot find class in classpath: Application1.Applicationlogintest

I have added dependencies for Selenium and web driver manager in my POM.xml file.
And added below in the class file.

```
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Karthik\\eclipse-    workspace\\NewSelenium\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.setBinary("C:\\Users\\Karthik\\Downloads\\chrome-win64\\chrome.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

`your text`